# DateTime in UTC with toISOString

Tags: javascript, datetime, iso8601

I have the following code:

```js
console.log(    
  new Date().toISOString()
)
```

This returns: `2021-10-14T08:28:28.467Z`
In my opinion it should return: `2021-10-14T08:28:28.000Z`. The difference is the **000Z**. In all examples (documentation) I see that it returns 000Z. In my case it doesn't.

How to make sure I also get the 000Z?

Comment: You get that with examples [like the one the MDN provides](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString#using_toisostring), because there a new Date object is created, that explicitly does not have any milliseconds. You are using just `new Date()`, which _will_ have them, unless your code happened to execute exactly when the milliseconds were zero, which has a chance of 1 in thousand to happen.

Comment: Why exactly should it return `000Z`? JavaScript dates represent ***milliseconds*** since unix epoch.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the date yourself, you do get the 0s default if not you get the hh,mm,ss,sss the time has at the time the statement executes –

You have to set the milliseconds if you want 000

Not sure why you would expect 000Z

```js
const d = new Date()
d.setMilliseconds(0)
console.log(d.toISOString())
```

Comment: I different documentation, they do not set the miliseconds. Why are those miliseconds being used?

Comment: Why would they not? [The documentation shows them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) what documentation do you have? [ECMA](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)

Comment: Check that documentation of your first link. I don't see any preset of the setMilliseconds. It does output 000Z. So no seconds.

Comment: @nhatimme no rocket science. The two examples on that page create a date object, and explicitly set it to `05 October 2011 14:48 UTC`. Notice that the input date does not contain any seconds and milliseconds. You should actually be asking why `(new Date).toISOString()` does not return `:00` seconds unlike those MDN examples.

Comment: If you set the date yourself, you do get the 0s default if not you get the hh,mm,ss,sss the time has at the time the statement executes